# null in variable arguments (dot notation)

Tags: java

Is there an idiomatic way to handle `null` arguments in variable arguments lists (with the dot notation)?I've found it's a bit clunky when there is only one `null`, argument. Below code throws NPE on marked line.

```
public class FooMain {

    public static boolean checkIsOneOf(String value, String ... acceptedValues) {
        for (String acceptedValue : acceptedValues) {
            // do stuff
        }
       return false;
   }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(checkIsOneOf("foo", "a", null));
        System.out.println(checkIsOneOf("foo", "a"));
        System.out.println(checkIsOneOf("foo", null)); // NPE
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if `acceptedValues` is null before you iterate through the items.

Answer (score 2):

A simple cast on the line marked 'NPE' solves the issue:

```
System.out.println(checkIsOneOf("foo", (String) null)); // no longer NPE
```